# Making 2 playbooks into 1 playbook

Tags: ansible

So I am using ansible-playbook to fix my logrotate on on more than 100 servers and each has 5-7 logrotate.d items to change. I know how to fix it with just 1 item but I can't seem to figure out how do you put more than 1 into the playbook to change, logic tells me to just list them under each other but then it started skipping everything apart from the first one instead. So ill include 2 separate playbooks here and can someone tell me how to make them into 1 playbook?

I have tried listing the - name part but that doesn't work.

```
---
- hosts: '{{ server }}'
  remote_user: ansip
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "server"
      prompt: "Enter server name or all"
      private: no

  tasks:
  roles:
    - role: ansible-role-logrotate
      logrotate:
        compress: true
        create: true
        weekly: true
        dateext: true
        include: /etc/logrotate.d
        rotate: 3
        shred: true
      logrotate_d:
        - name: samba
          files:
            - /var/log/samba/*
          options:
            compress: true
            dateext: true
            rotate: 3

- hosts: '{{ server }}'
  remote_user: ansip
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  roles:
    - role: ansible-role-logrotate
      logrotate:
        compress: true
        create: true
        weekly: true
        dateext: true
        include: /etc/logrotate.d
        rotate: 3
        shred: true
      logrotate_d:
        - name: httpd
          files:
            - /var/log/httpd/*log
          options:
            compress: true
            dateext: true
            rotate: 3
...
```

So with Appu help ive gotten to this:

```
  logrotate_d:
    - name: "{{ item.name }}"
      files:
        - "{{ item.logpath }}" / "{{ item.name }}"/*log
      options:
        compress: true
        dateext: true
        rotate: 3
      with_items:
        - { name: 'samba', logpath: '/log/var' }
        - { name: 'httpd', logpath: '/log/var' }
```

However, it doesn't seem to like the "/" in between logpath and name. Think it is missing quotes as well and if I add the quotas it still thinks the same. I only added spaces in both sides cuz otherwise, the quotes go crazy and don't even stop, makes entire playbook red.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested it, but you can use "with_items" by specifying required fields list under that.

```
  tasks:
  roles:
    - role: ansible-role-logrotate
      logrotate:
        compress: true
        create: true
        weekly: true
        dateext: true
        include: /etc/logrotate.d
        rotate: 3
        shred: true
      logrotate_d:
        - name: "{{ item.o }}"
          file: /"{{ item.l }}"/"{{ item.o }}"/*
          options:
            compress: true
            dateext: true
            rotate: 3
      with_items:
        - { o: 'samba', l: 'var/log' }
        - { o: 'httpd', l: '/tmp' }
...
```

Comment: Wow this looks very legit ill give it a GO right away, thanks :D

Comment: kudos.. accept the answer if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Ahh sadly no, thisone produces an error instantly. Playbook thinks the first - name line is missing quoates.

Comment: may be i would have missed double quotes, check the updated one. i would recommend you to paste output error.

Comment: And plus not all the logs are in /var/log so that would also complicate things. I somehow need to define all 5 seperatly, just have no clue how to do that in a playbook.

Comment: The error appears to have been in '/home/ansip/taristu/logrotate.yml': line 24, 
    column 18, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:

          logrotate_d:
            - name: {{ item.name }}
                     ^ here
    We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
    missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
    start a value. For instance:

Comment: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansip/taristu/logrotate.yml': line 26, column 35, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

          files:
            - "{{ item.logpath }}"/"{{ item.name }}"/*log
                                  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instan

Comment: it would appear to many quotes make it go crazy aswell. Somehow it dosent close out the last quotes. But my god ur lines look badass :D

Comment: i have not technically tested the role "ansible-role-logrotate", but i have pasted the code that actually worked for me with (dummy role i can say). atlease i didnt found any error related to with_items and their corresponding variables.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Sadly fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"} is what i get. Somehow the quotes do not end and leave the entire playbook red. I dont know how to post a picture of that in here to show you what i mean but the / in the 14th line of your code dosent let the quotes end.

Comment: If i put spaces between them then the quotes will end but it still wont see the item.

Answer (score 0):

Okei so i did it, Thanks you all for your help. I couldnt get the with_items working so i went back to the original idea of listing all things and somehow now it started working while earlier i couldnt get it to work.

```
- hosts: '{{ server }}'
  remote_user: ansip
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars_prompt:
- name: "server"
  prompt: "Enter server name or all"
  private: no

  tasks:
  roles:
    - role: ansible-role-logrotate
      logrotate:
        compress: true
        create: true
        weekly: true
        dateext: true
        include: /etc/logrotate.d
        rotate: 3
        shred: true
      logrotate_d:
        - name: samba
          files:
            - /var/log/samba/*
          options:
            compress: true
            dateext: true
            rotate: 3


          - name: httpd
           files:
             - /var/log/httpd/*
           options:
             compress: true
             dateext: true
             rotate: 3


         - name: syslog
           files:
             - /var/log/cron/*
             - /var/log/maillog/*
             - /var/log/messages/*
             - /var/log/secure/*
             - /var/log/spooler/'
           options:
             compress: true
             dateext: true
             rotate: 3
```

Comment: Best be noted that logrotate i manged to only get working with ansible 2.7. I also have earlier version installed and it mentions that a plugin is missing and so does not work!